# Como indexar una extensa drop down list en python-Selenium

Tags: html, python, selenium-webdriver

Ante todo buenas tardes. Estoy intentando desarrollar un programa para poder acelerar la carga de datos en formularios web, esto se debe a que al abrir un nuevo formulario, este empieza a contabilizar el tiempo, y reducir los tiempos en este caso es lo que se busca.

Dado lo anterior, la idea es diseñar un programa intermedio, donde el usuario interactúe con el mismo, pueda seleccionar las opciones que figurarían en la pagina web del formulario y posteriormente con un click autocompletar el formulario en la web en un tiempo mucho mas reducido.

Hasta ahora me funciono, en los casilleros mas sencillos, el del extraer el Xpath y junto a selenium clickear y enviar el texto deseado, hasta ahí todo bien.

El problema esta que dentro de los formularios, tengo unas DropDown list donde hay que seleccionar la localidad, dentro de de cada provincia. El tema es que en total, son mas de 2600 opciones disponibles, y asociar el xpath a mano uno a uno, se vuelve algo bastante engorroso.

Como el programa no puede leer el código html en tiempo real(ya que sino se contabilizaría el tiempo), se me ocurrió que el usuario pueda escribir manualmente la localidad, pero no se como hacer que el programa busque una coincidencia de ese input con los title="" de cada opción, ya que si el usuario se confunde en algún acento, coma, o espacio no funcionaria.

En si quisiera saber, si es que hay alguna forma de poder "extraer" los xpath y asociarlos al title="" correspondiente de una manera mas automatizada, para después adjuntarlo dentro del código y armar una lista para que el usuario seleccione.

Añado parte del codigo de html donde tengo que extreaer esos xpath y asociarlos al titulo:

```
    <select name="localidad.id" class="select" id="localidad.id">
<option value="null">Seleccione Localidad</option>
<option value="376">12 de Octubre</option>
<option value="33">16 de Julio</option>
<option value="443">17 de Agosto</option>
<option value="584">25 de Mayo</option>
<option value="558">30 de Agosto</option>
<option value="383">9 de Julio</option>
<option value="357">Abbott</option>
<option value="418">Acevedo</option>
<option value="12">Adolfo Gonzales Chaves (Est. Chaves)</option>
<option value="272">Agustina</option>
<option value="575">Agustín Mosconi</option>
<option value="271">Agustín Roca</option>
<option value="297">Alberdi Viejo</option>
<option value="16">Alberti (Est. Andrés Vaccarezza)</option>
<option value="87">Alejandro Petión </option>
<option value="374">Alfredo Demarchi (Est. Facundo Quiroga)</option>
<option value="23">Almirante Brown</option>
```

!!Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Si nos mostrarás el código seria mucho más fácil ayudar y entender el problema

Comment: Buenas tardes Christian, ahi adjunte parte del codigo HTML que muestra las distintas opciones. Eso es lo que necesitaria convertir a una matriz, donde se asocia el titulo con el xpath correspondiente. Muchas gracias